# How much RAM can the 945GZ MICRO 775 SE motherboard support?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I found two websites that have details on my motherboard (945GZ MICRO 775 SE):

1. [Intel® 945GZ Express Chipset](http://ark.intel.com/chipset.aspx?familyID=22687)
2. [Biostar USA > Products > Motherboards > 945GZ MICRO 775 SE](http://www.biostar-usa.com/mbdetails.asp?model=945GZ%20MICRO%20775%20SE)

Which one should I trust? In other words, what is the maximum number of RAM I can have on my motherboard?

Intel says that I can have 4 GB of RAM.
Biostar says I can have 2 GB of RAM and "supports up to 2GB memory".

I think that Biostar is saying that I can only have a maximum of 2 GB of RAM per slot.

Answer (score 3):

2 DDR2 DIMM memory slots (supports up to 2GB memory)

You can have 2 memory modules, up to 2GB total.

So 1GB and 1GB, or 2GB and empty, etc.

More than 2GB? No.

You'll get the best speed from two 1GB matched modules.

Comment: darn it. I wanted more ram.

Comment: Start saving your pennies for more mobo :)

Comment: But I found another website http://ark.intel.com/chipset.aspx?familyID=22687  and it says my motherboard can support 4 gb of ram.

Comment: You can try, but that says your *chipset* is capable of handling the memory - but your mobo manufacturer says the *board* can't. I'm not sure if there's an important technological difference for memory management, having never designed a motherboard... Just don't spend too much money knowing it might not work out :)

Answer (score 2):

I would personally trust the Biostar website more than Intel, but at the same time, I would try it myself.

Intel is simply listing the most that the chipset supports - this could be based on a motherboard with 4 sockets and it actually only supports 1GB sticks.

That being said, the Biostar website is unclear, it could be per stick or the actual maximum. That being said, 2GB does seem low for a Pentium D based motherboard, but they could just be covering themselves in case of problems.

If I was you, email them and ask - you have nothing to lose.

Answer (score 1):

- Maximum is **2 GB RAM**. This Site describes its [Features](http://www.driverdownloading.com/Driver/945GZ_Micro_775_SE_6x_On-Board_VGA.html) .
- **BioStar is correct**

> MEMORY Support Dual Channel DDR2
>
> 400/533 MHz 2 x DDR2 DIMM Memory Slot
>
> **Max. Supports up to 2GB Memory**

- This  [**Site**](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813138049)  also says **Max. 2 GB**

Answer (score 0):

Trust Biostar, Biostar made the motherboard.  The intel website is referring to the chipset, the chipset is a part used on the motherboard, but the motherboard may have implementation specific restrictions that it imposes.

BTW, the wording on the Bioware site isn't really clear, but I would read it as "supports up to a *maximum* of 2GB of ram".